# How to make all my onclick event clickable in ios browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am using HTML5/JqueryMobile to create web page.And i know onclick function in not work on ios device  browser.How can i change all the onclick event accessible to tap?so that i can tap on ios device browser.

This is only work on uniqueID that i create.

```
  $("#Button").tap(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("test");
});
```

I want all onclick event to be tap.Any idea?

Comment: `$(document).on('tap', function ()` is this what you mean?

Comment: which mean i add this script will change all my 'onclick=blahblah function()' to be clickable on ios browser?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will catch all `tap` events on your `document`.

```
$(document).on('tap', function () {
 $('<p>tap</p>').appendTo('#content'); // example
});
```

This works on iOS browsers as well as desktop browsers (*tested*).

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
 <div data-role="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
 </div>
 <div data-role="content" id="content">Tap events</div>
  <div data-role="footer">
  <h4>Footer</h4>
 </div>
</div>
```